# Redirect to top when enabled dispatch function in React Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, next.js

I am developing a simple E-commerce site with Next.js & Redux, but facing a wired problem like every time after clicking on `add-to-cart` it's scrolling to top, here is my below code.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const handleAddToCart = (id) => {
    dispatch({
        type: 'ADD_TO_CART',
        id
    })
  // console.log("clicked")
}
```

The JSX

```
<button
    className="default-btn"
    onClick={() => handleAddToCart(id)}>
    Add To Cart
</button>
```

When I disable the `dispatch` function like below section

```
dispatch({
    type: 'ADD_TO_CART',
    id
})
```

then it's not going to top after a click on `button`

what I have done wrong here.

What should I do now?

Please.

Thanks

Comment: please provide more code. in order to see how is your component and its connection to the store. it might be unmounted and mounted. but it's just a guess until I can see more of implementation.

Comment: It may be the default button click event 'submitting' the page. The HTML `button` has a default attribute of `type="submit"`. Try adding `type="button"` to your button element, or `event.preventDefault()` in your click handler, and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: @LyndenNoye Tried with both, which you have described but it's same

Comment: could you update your code to show a bit more of your component?

Comment: @LyndenNoye here is my store file https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-redux/store.js